# Defining ref class in C++

Tags: class, header, c++-cli

I am create ref class in my code named Picture inside the class there properties like `Bitmap^` `Sytem::String path` and others. I want to create a new property which indicates the shape of the picture.

I want to have three different shape classes, one is a square, one a horizontal rectangle, and the last a vertical rectangle. By looking at the BitMap pixel width and height I want to be able to change the property of my Picture to match one of the three classes. The issue is I have no idea how I would do this. To give an example, say I have this rectangle:

```
 _____________________
|                     |
|                     |
|_____________________|

Picture->TemplateType = HORIZONTALRECTANGLE
```

So far my picture class looks like this:

```
    public ref class Picture{
public: 
    System::String^ path;   
    BitMap^ image;  
    PosOnSlide *PositionAtributes;
    bool EmptyPic;
    bool PlacedOnSlide; 
};
```

I could always do this

```
    public ref class Picture{
public: 
    System::String^ path;   
    BitMap^ image;  
    PosOnSlide *PositionAtributes;
    bool EmptyPic;
    bool PlacedOnSlide;
            int TemplateType // 0 = square, 1 = vertical, 2 = horrizontal   
};
```

But I thought it would be easier for code maintenance to #define a class or enum, or something that has three different properties.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right using an **enum** could be a simple solution:

```
enum class PictureType
{
    Square,
    HorizontalRectangle,
    VerticalRectangle
};

public ref class Picture
{
public: 
    System::String^ path;   
    BitMap^ image;  
    PosOnSlide *PositionAtributes;
    bool EmptyPic;
    bool PlacedOnSlide;
    PictureType Type;
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Picture^ picture = gcnew Picture();
    picture->Type = PictureType::Square;

    return 0;
}
```

But you may want to **separate your types and produce different instances depending on the bitmap properties**:

```
public ref class Picture
{
public: 
    System::String^ path;   
    BitMap^ image;  
    PosOnSlide *PositionAtributes;
    bool EmptyPic;
    bool PlacedOnSlide;
    Picture(System::String^ path, BitMap^ bitmap)
    {
        this->path = path;
        this->image = bitmap;
    }
};

public ref class Square : Picture
{
public:
    Square(System::String^ path, BitMap^ bitmap)
        : Picture(path, bitmap)
    {
    }
};

public ref class HorizontalRectangle : Picture
{
public:
    HorizontalRectangle(System::String^ path, BitMap^ bitmap)
        : Picture(path, bitmap)
    {
    }
};

public ref class VerticalRectangle : Picture
{
public:
    VerticalRectangle(System::String^ path, BitMap^ bitmap)
        : Picture(path, bitmap)
    {
    }
};

public ref class PictureFactory
{
public:
    static Picture^ GetPicture(System::String^ path, BitMap^ bitmap)
    {
        Picture^ picture = nullptr;
        if (bitmap->Height == bitmap->Width)
        {
            picture = gcnew Square(path, bitmap);
        }
        else if (bitmap->Height < bitmap->Width)
        {
            picture = gcnew HorizontalRectangle(path, bitmap);
        }
        else if (bitmap->Height > bitmap->Width)
        {
            picture = gcnew VerticalRectangle(path, bitmap);
        }

        return picture;
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Picture^ square = PictureFactory::GetPicture("image.jpg", gcnew BitMap(100, 100));
    Picture^ hrect = PictureFactory::GetPicture("image.jpg", gcnew BitMap(100, 10));
    Picture^ vrect = PictureFactory::GetPicture("image.jpg", gcnew BitMap(10, 100));

    System::Console::WriteLine(square->GetType());
    System::Console::WriteLine(hrect->GetType());
    System::Console::WriteLine(vrect->GetType());

    return 0;
}
```

It depends on how you use the objects, the simpler the better. :)